# PHP how to know if multi-byte needs converstion?

Tags: php, encoding, multibyte

I have a problem with a system that response, somehow depends on it's mood.

Sometimes TÃ•NIS is returned and sometimes TÕNIS

and the result is concatenated to a string and compared in a function against another string so the data is valid.

The problem that this is valid TÕNIS but this is not TÃ•NIS

To solve this problem I use this function

```
mb_convert_encoding('TÃ•NIS', 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
```

And it works but there is also a problem since the response sometimes is correct
and this function will convert a good letter to � and this will become invalid.

Is there a way to check if the response is showed in multi-bytes or in plain letter?

Keep in mind this is one of many characters that has this problem.

And I cannot control the response that I get. The only way to fix this issues by solving it on my end

Comment: You need to **handle encodings correctly** all throughout your system. A system is not "moody", somebody has just not handled encodings correctly at some point. You must never *guess* what a string looks like, you must *know*. If you don't know, that's your issue that you need to trace back to its root cause. Start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: When I wanted to say "moody" this is what I meant "moody" - somebody has just not handled encodings correctly at some point. No need to explain it to me that something is set up incorrectly. I knnow that.   And there is no way we can control the response we get from the system, thus we need to handle it on our side

Answer (score -1):

So after long searching and trial and errors

```
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
    if(mb_check_encoding($result)){
        return $result;
    }else{
        return $string;
    }
```

After you encode TÕNIS this it will corrupt the encoding on the string
While TÃ•NIS on this will properly convert to TÕNIS and the encoding will be valid